# How to combine two tables to get desired result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables device and product. the device table have columns id and device.
and product table have columns id and product.

the ***device*** table is

```
id     device

 1       a                 
 2       b                  
 3       b
```

the ***product*** table is

```
id     product

 1       x     
 2       y        
 3       z       
 4       s
```

i need the result as

```
 id     device

  1       a    
  2       b        
  3       b       
  4      null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like

```
SELECT  p.id,
        d.device
FROM    product p LEFT JOIN
        device d    ON  p.id = d.id
```

Also, have a look at [SQL SERVER – Introduction to JOINs – Basic of JOINs](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select p.id,d.device from products p outer join device d
 on d.id=p.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this join

```
 select p.id,d.Device 
       from tblDevice d 
       right join tblProduct p
       on d.id=p.id
```